# JAKARTA POI Remove entire row to a Excel (not only content)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to remove entirely a ROW using JAKARTA POI. 
I use this method:

```
HSSFSheet sheet= wb.getSheetAt(0);
HSSFRow row = hoja.getRow(15);
sheet.removeRow(row);
```

but the problem is that it only removes the content of the cells. Not de entire row.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `HSSFSheet.shiftRows` function. [Example](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi-examples/3.7-beta1/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/ShiftRows.java)

```
 HSSFSheet.shiftRows(int startRow, int endRow, int n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @CycDemo.
I use this:

```
HSSFSheet hoja = wb.getSheetAt(0);
HSSFRow fila = hoja.getRow(numFila);
hoja.removeRow(fila);
hoja.shiftRows(numFila+1, hoja.getLastRowNum(), -1);
```

And it work fine!!!